# Devise wrong redirect using devise_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

If I enter an invalid username or password in 
`/admin/sign_in`. 
Devise redirect to `/administrators/sign_in` instead of `/admin/sign_in`.

This is my `routes.rb`

```rb
devise_for :administrators
devise_scope :administrator do
  get "/admin/sign_in" => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

`rake routes | grep sing_in`:

```sh
new_administrator_session GET   /administrators/sign_in  devise/sessions#new
administrator_session     POST  /administrators/sign_in  devise/sessions#create
admin_sign_in             GET   /admin/sign_in           devise/sessions#new
```

I'm running:

- ruby '2.1.2'
- rails '4.2.0'
- devise '~> 3.4.1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `get` only adds to your existing routes. You need to stop Devise from creating the default session routes, and then create your own. Try adding changing your routes to:

```
  devise_for :administrators, :skip => [:sessions]
  as :user do
    get 'admin/sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'admin/sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'admin/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end
```

More info in the docs [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes).

Answer (score 0):

Change your routes to like this

```
devise_for :administrators, :skip => [:sessions]
devise_scope :administrator do
  get "/admin/sign_in" => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

Comment: This works but is necessary add `:as => :new_administrator_sessions` because devise generates paths with
`administrator` resource and the `get "/admin/sign_in" => "devise/sessions#new"` generates `new_admin_sessions` path. So the solution is the @ConstantM answer. Thanks for your response.